# real time messaging

Tags: .net, sockets, compact-framework

in my company there are more than 100 vehicles. And each vehicle has Windows Mobile device which is connected to internet over 3G.

My task is to write an application to be able to communicate with these vehicles real-time. Server and client side.

Here is the list that i have to take care.

- Minimum bandwith use. (Socket? TCP or UDP???)
- Connection is losing while on the move. Messages should be delivered succesfully.

Is there any protocol or server application suitable for these requirements?

Regards

Baro

Answer (score 3):

Just use HTTP, the overhead from HTTP headers isn't going to break the bandwidth bank.

The clients can just poll the server for the latest message. If the latest message has an ID difference greater than 1 from the last message the client has on record then the client can request the specific message ID it's missing directly (could be missing from a dropped client connection etc). A generic HTTP handler (ashx) or web service (asmx) is really all you need.

Comment: Do i have to make http polling? Because server can send a message to vehicles?

Comment: @bengin - With HTTP you have a handful of options, long polling (comet/ajax), using HTML5 web sockets or server events (EventSource).

Answer (score 0):

For this type of communication scenario, socket communication will be the best choice. Why ?

1). It happens using raw bytes.

2). There are options to have a connected communication and connectionless communication

3). .NET has a rich API to implement socket communication.

4). If used in conjunction of Rx and / or TPL (async await) it can be handled in much better way.

Minimum bandwidth use: TCP will add more header bytes to the actual message then UDP as TCP is connect (kind of) communication socket type and also has internal check-sum. UDP will be the best choice to save some bandwidth over 3G.

For connectivity and guaranteed confirmation of message delivery:
I would say the choice is solely yours or your company on what approach to go forward with.

Advantage of TCP: As it is connected communication, as soon as you are loosing connectivity both the end can come to know about the disconnection and can do connection again and its more reliable in message delivery.

Advantage of UDP: Its send and forget protocol so it cannot guarantee any reliability or connectivity as such in built, but as the bytes sent are costly in your case using UDP will be good options and use some kind of message protocol to implement end to end communication - Request / confirm with response mechanism. Thus the connection and message received and sent confirmation can be done manually.